# How to resolve a gwmi : Invalid class "WmiMonitorID" PowerShell error?

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-core, get-wmiobject

I getting the following error:

```
gwmi : Invalid class "WmiMonitorID"
At line:1 char:1
+ gwmi WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi | ForEach-Object {($_.UserFrie ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

while trying to grab my monitor's Serial ID using:

```
gwmi WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi | ForEach-Object {
    ($_.UserFriendlyName -notmatch 0 | foreach {[char]$_}) -join "";
    ($_.SerialNumberID -notmatch 0 | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
}
```

I used this command about 2 months back and it worked flawlessly. (Was not even running PowerShell in admin)

[image: code screenshot]

Now with or without admin I get the error mentioned above. (also tried x64 and x86 both with/without admin)

[image: error screenshot]

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: May be your WMI  is corrupt .Try these steps https://www.virtuallyboring.com/microsoft-wmi-invalid-class-error-0x80041010/

Comment: @TheGameiswar My `WMI Control (Local)` looks like the good one in the screenshot

Comment: The second screenshot looks as if there is an additional space in the class. You can see it in `Invalid Class " WmiMonitorID"` so it might be reading the whitespace.

Comment: @Drew Looks like you are right, but now there is a new error. https://i.imgur.com/jsRYonB.png

Comment: Now it looks like it is running each line independently instead of it being one larger expression.

Comment: @Drew Looks like you're right again. It was adding random spaces from wherever I c&p from. I guess this is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @Drew for pointing out the whitespace.

So it seems like whatever I was c&p the code from was adding extra spaces to the code which would make it end up looking like

`gwmi(Space)(Space)WmiMonitorID(Space)(Space)-Namespace`

or add extra spaces at the end

`... -join ""}(Space)(Space)`

The solution would be to copy it in a .txt or paste bin and make sure the extra spaces are not there before copying back to PowerShell.